# How to add a silverLight Reference in a C# application

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have installed ServicePack1 of VS 2008 and silverlight tools for VS2008 .

How to add reference to silverlight to my project .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your project, click "properties".

You should see a "Silverlight Applications" tab, click it... you can then "add" Silverlight project references to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can also drop the .xap file into a folder and reference it in the "Source" attribute of the asp:Silverlight control. You might need the System.Web.Silverlight.dll in the same folder for the control to render correctly.